# GROUP BY: SQLite and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

Two links: [Link 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50029/2) and [Link 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cc68b/4). Why different results in column value???? Correct result in MySQL version. What I have to do for the same result in SQLite version?

First table:

```
 CREATE TABLE Subjs 
 (
      id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
      subj        varchar(50)
  );



 INSERT INTO Subjs (subj) VALUES ('chair');
 INSERT INTO Subjs (subj) VALUES ('table');
```

Second table:

```
 CREATE TABLE Params 
 (
      id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
      param       varchar(50)
  );

 INSERT INTO Params (param) VALUES ('lenght');
 INSERT INTO Params (param) VALUES ('width');
 INSERT INTO Params (param) VALUES ('height');
```

Third table:

```
CREATE TABLE Subj_Param_value
(
 id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
 value       varchar(50), 
 subj_id     INTEGER NOT NULL,
 param_id   INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Subj_Param_value (value, subj_id, param_id) VALUES ('20', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO Subj_Param_value (value, subj_id, param_id) VALUES ('30', 1, 2);
INSERT INTO Subj_Param_value (value, subj_id, param_id) VALUES ('150', 1, 3);

INSERT INTO Subj_Param_value (value, subj_id, param_id) VALUES ('30', 2, 1);
INSERT INTO Subj_Param_value (value, subj_id, param_id) VALUES ('20', 2, 2);
INSERT INTO Subj_Param_value (value, subj_id, param_id) VALUES ('90', 2, 3);

INSERT INTO Subj_Param_value (value, subj_id, param_id) VALUES ('30', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO Subj_Param_value (value, subj_id, param_id) VALUES ('60', 1, 2);
INSERT INTO Subj_Param_value (value, subj_id, param_id) VALUES ('170', 1, 3);
```

Query:

```
select * from (
select * from Subj_Param_value ORDER BY id DESC
) t, Subjs, Params
where 
Subjs.id=t.subj_id
and Params.id=t.param_id
and Subjs.id=1
group by t.param_id;
```

I want to get the latest values ​​from a third table for all the params ​​from the second table for a particular record from the first table. For example, the most recent value of the length, width and height for the chair.

Different result in SQLite and MySQL... I need result in SQLite version like in  MySQL version. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you explain exactly what your tables are for, how they're set up, and the result you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to get the latest values ​​from a third table for all the params ​​from the second table for a particular record from the first table. For example, the most recent value of the length, width and height for the chair.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `GROUP BY`, the SQL standard requires that all the *other* selected columns must use aggregate functions.

MySQL and SQLite do not throw an error in this case, but just give you some random record from the group.
That you get different records is caused by the different implementations.

An `ORDER BY` in a subquery has no *guaranteed* effect on the order in the outer query.

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can force to use one specific record from the group if you use `MIN` or `MAX`.
So your problem can be solved like this:

```
SELECT *, MAX(Subj_Param_Value.id)
FROM Subjs, Subj_param_value, Params
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cc68b/10)